# Hadoop - Input path does not exist

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, hadoop, mapreduce

I did set up the hadoop Ubuntu OS, followed all the necessary steps,
1.created the hdfs file system
2.Moved the text files to input directory
3.having privilege to access all the directories.
but when run the simple word count example, i got

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/user/root/input
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:224)
```

but, input path is valid and even can able view the files in that path from eclipse itself, so plz assist were i am wrong.

attached the screenshot for the reference
[image]

Comment: In a terminal, what do you get back if you execute `hadoop fs -ls /user/root/input`? Just want to verify your DFS is accessible through there too, other than just eclipse.

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl, Result:root@master:/usr/local/hadoop-0.20.2# bin/hadoop fs -ls /user/root/input
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   1 root supergroup        405 2013-04-16 15:07 /user/root/input/sigle
-rw-r--r--   1 root supergroup        302 2013-04-12 15:23 /user/root/input/single.txt                                                          Able to connect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following 2 lines in your code :

```
config.addResource(new Path("/HADOOP_HOME/conf/core-site.xml"));
config.addResource(new Path("/HADOOP_HOME/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
```

Your client is looking into the local FS.

Comment: hi both lines are looking same, so do i need to add both. Instead of `/HADOOP_HOME/` do we have to mention the location of `conf` folder.

Comment: problem solved i have now used path with hdfs location, "hdfs://master:9000/user/root/input"

Comment: thanks, ur suggestion also worked, while replaced the `HADOOP_HOME` with my hadoop's `conf` folder location

Comment: @Tariq Can you please explain why does it look into local FS?

Answer (score 1):

For hadoop-2.2.0 on windows 7, I added the below lines and it solved the issue (NOTE: My Hadoop Home is: C:\MyWork\MyProjects\Hadoop\hadoop-2.2.0)

Configuration conf = new Configuration();

conf.addResource(new Path("C:\MyWork\MyProjects\Hadoop\hadoop-2.2.0\etc\hadoop\core-site.xml"));

conf.addResource(new Path("C:\MyWork\MyProjects\Hadoop\hadoop-2.2.0\etc\hadoop\hdfs-site.xml"));